# how to override servletContext and use it in tomcat7?

Tags: servlets, memcached

I want to use memcached to manage my project in tomcat cluster.And I use  “memcached session manager” to manage session with memcached ,now I want to override  servletContext‘s methods `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`.So that ,it can be transparent to developers.
Or any one has better solution?